# What is the correct URL format to send to an HTTP proxy server?

Tags: https, proxy, http-redirect

When my application requests a particular URL from a server (over https), it gets a 301 Moved Permanently redirection. However the Location header is badly-formed. I see something like this:

```
> GET https://myserver/url HTTP/1.1
< 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: https://redirectedserverhttp://myserver/url
```

If I send the request without the host, I get a correctly-formed URL:

```
> GET /url HTTP/1.1
< 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: https://redirectedserver/url
```

I am going through a proxy server and according to [RFC 2068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#section-5.1.2) section 5.1.2, "*The absoluteURI form is required when the request is being made to a proxy*" so it looks like I'm doing it the right way but the proxy is responding incorrectly. If I try this through a browser, curl, or wget it works fine. I looked at the wget code and the logic looks like:

```
if( proxy && !https ) {
    use absoluteURI
} else {
    use relativeURI
}
```

Wget even has a comment in its source code:

```
/* When using SSL over proxy, CONNECT establishes a direct
   connection to the HTTPS server.  Therefore use the same
   argument as when talking to the server directly. */
```

Is this an actual standard defined somewhere? If the absolute URI form is supposed to be used, why do the other tools **not** use it, and why is it failing?

Comment: If you listen for traffic you're network interface, you'll see near all http GET request in headers use relative path instead of full-path. instead of using Full path, you should consider use the Host line in the http(s) header (please notify @ me as I don't check for answers manually).

Comment: @user2284570: I'm trying to figure out the protocol when using SSL while talking to the proxy. A network sniffer won't tell me anything because the packets are encrypted.

Comment: Yes, but you can see the result for http. Also, by `I'm trying to figure out the protocol when using SSL while talking to the proxy`, are you meaning you want your proxy to detect if the protocol is sftp instead https for example?

Comment: I'm sending `GET https://<host>/<url>` in both the HTTP and HTTPS cases but with HTTPS, the proxy is responding with an invalid redirection URL. If I change it to `GET /<url>` it works, but according to the RFC mine should work as well. I'm trying to find out whether I should change my code to the `if( proxy && !https)` I listed or if my code is right and this particular proxy is wrong.

Answer (score 7):

You only send absolute URLs with HTTP. They are useless with HTTPS anyway *because the proxy does not see them*. It only sees the `CONNECT` header, everything else is encrypted.

It is not the proxy that responds with an invalid URL, it's the server itself. *The proxy cannot see or the response either* because it's encrypted as well.

Comment: Very good point. So I need to sent the absolute URL when connecting through a proxy using HTTP, and the relative URL otherwise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Normally, You send an http header with each http requests.
Here's an example built with the opera dragonfly tools for https://example.org:

```
GET / HTTPS/1.1
Host: example.org
User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64; Edition Next) Presto/2.12.378 Version/12.50
Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml xml, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1
Accept-Language: en
Accept-Charset: iso-8859-1, utf-8, utf-16, utf-32, *;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, x-gzip, identity, *;q=0
Connection: Keep-Alive, TE
TE: deflate, gzip, chunked, identity, trailers
```

response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sun, 24 Nov 2013 01:38:41 GMT
Etag: "359670651"
Expires: Sun, 01 Dec 2013 01:38:41 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT
Server: ECS (mia/41C4)
X-Cache: HIT
x-ec-custom-error: 1
Content-Length: 1270

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 50px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 1em;
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
        @media (max-width: 700px) {
            body {
                background-color: #fff;
            }
            div {
                width: auto;
                margin: 0 auto;
                border-radius: 0;
                padding: 1em;
            }
        }
        </style>    
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Example Domain</h1>
            <p>This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents.   You may use this
        domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
            <p><a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Since all browsers will send the request with a relative path, the proxy developers may decided it don't worth to bother with this part of the standard...

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I know that I can make it work in this particular case by sending `/url` instead of `http://host/url` but I need to know if this is a good _general_ solution to the problem, or if it will fix this proxy and break many others.

Comment: @GraemePerrow : If a proxy don't support relative path, it would means no web browsers can't use it since they use the `Host:` in the Http header instead of the full path. So, it shouldn't break other proxies...

Comment: @user2284570: The absoluteURI form is REQUIRED when the request is being made to a proxy ([RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5))